# within a kotlin lambda, how does a string accept a lambda?

Tags: lambda, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In gradle-kotlin-dsl... this is valid code

```
tasks {
   "build" {
      // inner lambda code here
```

How can it work that a string can accept a lambda parameter, or else how is this syntax working?  The string "build" seems to one of a list of strings that substitute for function calls?
Something in the applicable class definition must set up this behaviour, but I cannot think how that is done.

The way this works could be a technique that has other uses, but to evaluate that, it is necessary to know how it works!

Comment: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Conventions/Invoke/Task.kt

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of a couple of Kotlin language features which are often used for creating [DSLs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html), specifically:

- the invoke operator, which lets you define the `()` function call operator for a type, with an arbitrary parameter list ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke))
- being able to pass a last lambda parameter to a function outside the parantheses you usually need for the parameter list ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter))
- extensions, letting you add new methods to existing types, even if you don't own them ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html))

To achieve the syntax you've asked about specifically, you could write a method like this:

```
operator fun String.invoke(block: () -> Unit) {
    // Do whatever you'd like with the String and the lambda
    // you received as a parameter
}
```

The lambda you're taking as the parameter could also be an extension on any type you'd like (perhaps `String` itself, but depends on your use case), could take parameters, or be expected to return a value instead of just `Unit`.

The point is that inside this extension, you'll have access to the `String` it was called on as `this` and you'll have the lambda that was passed to it.

---

For further reference, [here's](https://proandroiddev.com/writing-dsls-in-kotlin-part-1-7f5d2193f277) a multi-part article that shows off some DSL building techniques.